# using jdbc to export data into xml document

Tags: jdbc, xml-parsing

This may seem to be dumb to ask.. I'm very new to jdbc and trying to follow a tutorial. The tutorial is trying to store the XML data in a parsed form, provided by 'mapping.xml'. Below is the sample code:

```
 public static void main (String args[]) {
    Document mapping = null;
    Document dataDoc = null;
    Document newDoc = null;
      try {

          DocumentBuilderFactory dbfactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          DocumentBuilder docbuilder = dbfactory.newDocumentBuilder();
          mapping = docbuilder.parse("mapping.xml");
          dataDoc = docbuilder.newDocument();

          //Instantiate the new Document
          newDoc = docbuilder.newDocument();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Errors with creating document: "+e.getMessage());
       }
```

However, after running through the codes, no new XML document is created, neither exception is caught. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!!

Comment: Your code does two things: parsing existing `mapping.xml` file and creating new XML document (DOM object) in memory. Neither reading from JDBC nor storing any file is not present above...

Comment: Hello Tomasz, I have updated the code area with all info except the jdbc connection part. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't really *storing* any XML document here, you barely create a *DOM representation* of the XML document in memory. In order to actually store the file you need the following code snippet:

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
Result result = new StreamResult(new File("output.xml"));
Source source = new DOMSource(dataDoc);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

3rd line is crucial.

BTW ask someone to review your code:

- Methods are way too long
- Uou aren't handling exceptions correctly
- DOM might not be the best choice for exporting large amounts of data

Comment: Thanks Tomasz! I added the above codes but got an error msg from line 3 saying -- Type mismatch: cannot convert from StreamResult to DirStateFactory.Result       do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @zoe: I can only guess that changing 3rd line to: `javax.xml.transform.Result result = `... - will help.